# Añadir a un dataframe una columna que contiene las medias de factores

Tags: r, dataframe, matrices, rstudio

Soy nuevo programando, y para un ejercicio que estoy haciendo me piden agregar al dataframe que ya tengo creado y modificado, una columna que contiene la media de la esperanza de vida agrupada por divisiones/regiones (otra columna del data frame).

El caso es que he al final he conseguido añadir esa columna a mi dataframe pero cuando paso el codigo de pruebas me da error, he pensado que puede ser porque tambien se aplica a la última fila 'Medias' que no se le corresponde ninguna region porque no es un estado, es simplemente una fila que recoge las medias de todas las columnas.

En resumen, me gustaría encontrar el error en mi código que hace que no pase ese test, si alguien me pudiera ayudar y explicarmelo estaría enormemente agradecido.

Os dejo por aquí el dataframe con todas las modificaciónes, una vez ejecutado todo, partid desde la variable 'state.df.abb', ese es el df final:

```
state.df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
estados.a.pos = endsWith(rownames(state.df), "a")
estados.a.mask = !estados.a.pos
state.df[!estados.a.mask,8] <- NA
state.df = rbind(state.df,Medias=colMeans(state.df,na.rm = TRUE))
rownames(state.df)[1:50] <- paste(state.abb)
state.df.abb = state.df
division = factor(c(as.character(state.division), NA))
state.df.abb = cbind(state.df,Division=division)
```

Aquí esta la variable esperanza.media:

```
esperanza.media = tapply(state.df$`Life Exp`, division, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Por último, aquí está el dataframe final, con la columna 'Division.esperanza.media':

```
state.df.abb = cbind( state.df, 
                      Division=c(as.character(state.division),"NA"), 
                      Division.esperanza.media=c(esperanza.media[sapply( state.division, 
                                                                         function(x) which(names(esperanza.media) == x) )],mean(esperanza.media)) )
```

El test de pruebas que tiene que pasar es este:

```
stopifnot(round(mean(state.df.abb$Division.esperanza.media - state.df.abb[["Life Exp"]], na.rm = T), 17) == 1.99E-15 || round(mean(state.df.abb$Division.esperanza.media - state.df.abb[["Life.Exp"]], na.rm = T), 17) == 1.99E-15)
```

Alguien sabe por que no está pasando el código de pruebas o tiene alguna idea?
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: El primer problema lo tienes al generar `state.df.abb`,  O las filas deben ser 50 o 51 con la fila de medias. ¿Ese es el problema que dices? o ¿es el stopifnot que falla cuando esperas que no lo haga?

Comment: Ya actualicé el código, disculpa, es el stopifnot el que me falla, sospecho que es porque la columna division nueva que he creado tambien da valores a la fila 'Medias' y esto no debe ser así ya que 'Medias' no es un estado, como podría arreglar el codigo para que la columna 'Division.esperanza.media' me de datos hasta la fila 50?

Comment: Pero el `stopifnot` justamente genera una falla cuando no se cumple cierta condición, en tu caso es la comparación de una diferencia con respecto a un número muy pequeño que ciertamente no se cumple. ¿Tu duda es por que por ejemplo `mean(state.df.abb$Division.esperanza.media - state.df.abb[["Life Exp"]], na.rm = T)` no es igual a `1.99E-15`?

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos errores en tu código. Lo primero, en la segunda expresión dentro de,

```
stopifnot(round(mean(state.df.abb$Division.esperanza.media - state.df.abb[["Life Exp"]], na.rm = T), 17) == 1.99E-15 || round(mean(state.df.abb$Division.esperanza.media - state.df.abb[["Life.Exp"]], na.rm = T), 17) == 1.99E-15)
```

has indicado de manera incorrecta el nombre de la variable (el nombre correcto es **"Life Exp"**). Lo segundo, estas comparando los valores de las esperanzas de vida con la media de dichos valores por divisiones. A nivel matemático esos resultados no son lo mismo, que es lo que estas asegurando tu con la comparación (**== 1.99E-15**, que es prácticamente **0** para **R**).

Espero haberte ayudado!!